# Using Aria for Pioneer robot

Tags: ros, pioneer, rosaria, aria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I got a probem with running Pioneer. Please help me.
I installed a package ROSARIA and it works well.
But what i want to do is to move the robot by keyboard. By the way, I found that there are many source code in the Aria package such as ArActionKeydrive.cpp ArActionInput.cpp etc.
I want to know how to use these useful codes at the same time.

thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47131/using-aria-for-pioneer-robot/) by [Blake](https://answers.ros.org/users/3502/blake/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-10-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you say you installed ROSARIA do you mean you installed it on your machine connected to the robot. To control the robot you need to publish a Twist message on the cmd_vel topic. I believe the topic will be in the RosAria namespace (i.e. it will be /RosAria/cmd_vel) but you can confirm that with `rostopic list`.

You need to make sure that your keyboard drives nodes are publishing on the correct topic. You can again figure out which topic the keyboard are publishing on using `rostopic list`. If they are not publishing on the same topic that the ROSARIA node on your machine is subscribing to you need to remap the publishing topic either via the command line with `rosrun` or using a launch file.

As a quick example on how to remap topics if I had a node named node1 which published on topic /foo and I wanted to remap it to publish on /foo/bar I would run

```
rosrun <your package> node1 foo:=/foo/bar
```

You can read more about remapping here [Remapping Arguments](http://ros.org/wiki/Remapping%20Arguments)

---

Originally posted by [malvarado](https://answers.ros.org/users/3532/malvarado/) with karma: 80 on 2012-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1